# Unable to add Tab on Fan Page

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-page, facebook-apps

When I go to try and add a Tab to our Facebook Fan Page it gives me this message, stating "There are no settings for this application."

This makes me unable to actually add the tab.  Any suggestions?  Everything is filled out on the application page.

Answer (score 0):

Click Edit Settings for your app on the page: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

This will then give you some links on the left hand side. Click View App Profile Page then click Add to my Page and choose your page to add it too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the usual "App Profile Page" method no longer works for new pages unless you create a profile page for it manually. Facebook just made this a lot more complicated than it should be...but here are the details...

You can use this page to add it quickly:
http://www.addtab.info/

Or you can refer to this blog post for more info on how to create your own "Add tab" interface:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/

You can also use the API: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs